# implementing ioctl() commands in FreeBSD

Tags: c++, posix, freebsd, ioctl

I am adding some code to an existing FreeBSD device driver and I am trying to pass a `char*` from user space to the driver. I've implemented a custom `ioctl()` command using the `_IOW` macro like so: `#define TIBLOOMFILTER _IOW(0,253,char*)`

My call looks something like this:

```
int file_desc = open("/dev/ti0", O_RDWR);
ioctl(file_desc, TIBLOOMFILTER, (*filter).getBitArray());
close(file_desc);
```

When I call `ioctl()` I get: `Inappropriate ioctl for device` as an error message. Any guess as to what may be doing wrong? I've defined the same macro in my device driver, and added it to the `case` statement.

Comment: Please, post your code of ioctl handler in driver. And also post the registration of your driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you register your ioctl handler with

```
.d_ioctl  = ioctl_handler
```

in ?devsw (char/block device switch table)?

Comment: No, but the handler was already in place as it was an existing driver, I was just adding another command to the already written handler. Is this not correct?

Comment: Do you use right return code? 
Add debug prints just before the `switch` and after your `case`

Comment: We've tried this and it appears that the command is never even reaching the handle in the driver.

Comment: @thecoffman, then please, publish your driver (main parts, with devsw and ioctl handler)

Comment: was ioctl handler called (reached)? Can you use any other ioctl from existing driver? do you use the same parameters for _IOW(?,?,...)

Comment: It ended up being a pointer size issue. Its resolved now though. (sorry to resurrect such an old thread). Thanks for your help!